# column filter and multiplication in dask dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dask

I am trying to replicate the following operation on a dask dataframe where I have to filter the dataframe based on column value and multiply another column on that.

Following is pandas equivalent -

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

df['adjusted_revenue'] =  0
df.loc[(df.tracked ==1), 'adjusted_revenue'] = 0.7*df['gross_revenue']
df.loc[(df.tracked ==0), 'adjusted_revenue'] = 0.3*df['gross_revenue']
```

I am trying to do this on a dask dataframe but it doesn't support assignment.

`TypeError: '_LocIndexer' object does not support item assignment`

This is working for me -

```
df['adjusted_revenue'] =  0
df1 = df.loc[df['tracked'] ==1]
df1['adjusted_revenue'] = 0.7*df1['gross_revenue']
df2 = df.loc[df['tracked'] ==0]
df2['adjusted_revenue'] = 0.3*df['gross_revenue']
df = dd.concat([df1, df2])
```

However, I was hoping if there is any simpler way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: This is an issue specific to Dask. It seems like changing data in place isn't the simplest thing to do in a distributed computation framework such as Dask.
https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/2426

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`.apply`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.apply), which is probably the right thing to do with Pandas too; or perhaps `where`. However, to keep things as similar to your original, here it is with `map_partitions`, in which you act on each piece of the the dataframe independently, and those pieces really are Pandas dataframes.

```
def make_col(df):
    df['adjusted_revenue'] =  0
    df.loc[(df.tracked ==1), 'adjusted_revenue'] = 0.7*df['gross_revenue']
    df.loc[(df.tracked ==0), 'adjusted_revenue'] = 0.3*df['gross_revenue']
    return df

new_df = df.map_partitions(make_col)
```